# Making a state available throughout the app using useContext in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried to use `useContext` and looked through some YT videos but I dont think I am getting it...well clearly I am not. ha

I want to make `this.state.dropdown` available throughout the app, so I can make some conditional logic on its value.

```
// input.js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Button from '../components/button';
import { getData } from '../utils/debugger';
import { DropdownContext } from '../utils/DropdownContext';

// Make a separate function for axios call so that you can reuse it
function queryData(dropdownValue) {
  return axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `http://xxx/debugger/${dropdownValue}`,
  })
    .then((res) => res.data.map((k) => k['key']['name']))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}

class InputForm extends React.Component {
  // Just use the state property. No need to use constructor
  state = {
    isLoaded: false,
    dropdown: 'RTS',
    value: '',
    data: [],
  };

  // If you use arrow function then you don't have to
  // bind them in the constructor

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  handleDropdown = async (event) => {
    // Here we need to query the data from axios
    // If we get the data then we'll update the state
    // otherwise you may show any error message
    const value = event.target.value;

    try {
      const newData = await queryData(value);
      this.setState({ data: newData, dropdown: value });

      if (newData.length > 0) {
        this.setState({ value: newData[0] });
      }
      console.log('newData = ' + JSON.stringify(newData));
    } catch (ex) {
      console.error('Could not get data from axios');
    }
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    queryData(this.state.dropdown)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ data: data });
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
          this.setState({ value: data[0] });
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoaded: false });
        // Do other stuff here, may be show any error message?
        // Could not get data
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className='flex items-center'>
         <DropdownContext.Provide value={this.state.dropdown}>
          <select
            value={this.state.dropdown}
            onChange={this.handleDropdown}
            className='relative w-full bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm px-1 py-3 text-center cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm mr-5'>
            <option value='RTS'>RTS</option>
            <option value='RTB'>RTB</option>
            <option value='MPC'>MPC</option>
            <option value='MPC_DSP'>MPC_DSP</option>
          </select>
         </DropdownContext.Provide>

          <select
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className='relative w-full bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm px-1 py-3 text-left cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm mr-5'>
            {this.state.data.map((r) => (
              <option key={r} value={r}>
                {r}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>

          {console.log('---')}
          {console.log('these will be entered into the getData()')}
          {console.log(`this.state.dropdown = ${this.state.dropdown}`)}
          {console.log(`this.state.value = ${this.state.value}`)}

          <Button onClick={() => getData(this.state.dropdown, this.state.value)} color='green'>
            Generate
          </Button>
        </form>
      
    );
  }
}

export default InputForm;
```

```
// App.js
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';

import './index.css';

import Button from '../src/components/button';

import RTSButtons from '../src/components/rtsButtons';
import RTBButtons from '../src/components/rtbButtons';
import MPCButtons from '../src/components/mpcButtons';

import { DropdownContext } from '../src/utils/DropdownContext';

const sectionStyles = 'mt-5 border-b pb-5';

export default function App() {
  const [buttonStatus, setButtonStatus] = useState('rts');
  const dropdownState = useContext(DropdownContext);

  const switchButtons = (x) => {
    setButtonStatus(x);
  };

  let buttonName = 'RTS / MPC DSP';
  let buttons;

  if (buttonStatus === 'rts') {
    buttonName = 'RTS / MPC DSP';
    buttons = <RTSButtons />;
  } else if (buttonStatus === 'rtb') {
    buttonName = 'RTB';
    buttons = <RTBButtons />;
  } else if (buttonStatus === 'mpc') {
    buttonName = 'MPC';
    buttons = <MPCButtons />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <section id='response' className={`flex justify-between ${sectionStyles}`}>
        <div>
          <Button onClick={() => switchButtons('rts')} color='gray'>
            RTS / MPC DSP
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => switchButtons('rtb')} color='gray'>
            RTB
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => switchButtons('mpc')} color='gray'>
            MPC
          </Button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Button color='red'>
            <a href='http://exchange-debugger' target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>
              create a capture
            </a>
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => console.log('Feedback was giving')} color='purple'>
            <a
              href='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfzebOfAeXqGLqAp5E1l2fW1nTqSzYRwpqKG56HPXey9GQLcA/viewform'
              target='_blank'
              rel='noreferrer'>
              feedback
            </a>
          </Button>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section>
        <h2 className='font-bold text-2xl capitalize -mb-10 mt-2'>{buttonName}</h2>
        {dropdownState} // <-- just testing the value here
      </section>

      <section>{buttons}</section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// DropdownContext.js
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const DropdownContext = createContext(null);
```

These are my components but i am getting the following error:

**Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `InputForm`.**

I am not too sure where to look next anyone can assist that would be great

Comment: `useContext` is a hook, it does not work in class components. You also have to have the context provider above all children in the render tree that you want to be able to access the context, as [per the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

Comment: how can i do something similar using a class and a function component? Or is there a way to convert my functioning class component into a function one?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the React docs: "Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level". The state to pass down is defined in your `InputForm` class, so using a context would allow you access `state.dropdown` in the component tree of `InputForm`. It seems like you want to access the state from the `App` class, but I cannot see that such a component is part of the component tree of `InputForm`. If that is the case, then you would need to define the state in a common ancestor of the components, and move the `DropdownContext.Provider` to that ancestor.